# How can I filter specific rows from an Excel spreadsheet based on criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet from which I need to select ONLY the first five rows in each category.

[image]

I only want columns `A` and `B` when `C` is less than 5 -- `=IF($C1>5,$A1,)` and `=IF($C1>5,$B1,)` -- but I would like to exclude blank rows when `$Cn` is greater than 4.

In a perfect world, there would be a function that I could append as the "fail" condition, giving me this: `=IF($C1>5,$A1,[insert next instance of $An where $C1<5])

Any ideas on making this simple?

Comment: What version are you using? Have you tried using filters rather than formulas?

Comment: Excel 2010, and no, I've not tried filters. A project for this morning. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a row below the category "I HAVE" and add column labels at the top of the column. Go to the `Data` tab and click `Filter`. This will add filter buttons to the column labels.

[image]

Click the drop down for the last column (I called it "Count"). Point to `Number Filters` and then `Custom Filter`. Select the first criteria to be `Greater than` and place a `0` in the next field. Leave `And` selected and then choose the criteria `Less than` in the next set. Place a `5` in the next field.

[image]

Click `OK` and it will filter out the rows which have a count of `0` and are less than `5`. You will need to do the same thing for the other category of "I WANT".

Answer (score 1):

Use Autofilter to show only rows with values less than 5.